# how to cut table cells to end of text in html

Tags: html, css

I am fairly new to HTML and CSS so am struggling with a cell spacing problem.

I am trying to stop the cell space when the text ends although all my attempts have not worked and online resources have no either. This is my code:

```css
h1 {
  color: blue;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, th, td {
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-spacing: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

th {
  background-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<h1>Packing Note</h1>
<table style="width:60%" cellspacing="0.2" cellpadding="0.2">
 <tr>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Item Name</th>
    <th>Sent</th>
    <th>To Follow</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>X</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have tried `border-collapse` which is suggested online which has not worked. I have also tried padding and width which haven't changed it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

style="width:60%" cellspacing="0.2" cellpadding="0.2"

Try to delete this from the table element and it might give you the result you want.
As this line has higher priority than your stylesheet code.